# GUI logon into remote system

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, debian

I'm looking for something similar to RDP for linux.

I know VNC, but it does not work like RDP - it just sends images of screen, mouse position, keystrokes, etc. RDP just sends info that I've just clicked the button-widget.

I know I can forward Xs (I'm currently using this), but this way i can use only windows I opened from console. Also, it works nice only with small gtk or qt based applications. Running eclipse is a nightmare.

What I'm looking for is to work remotely as if I was working on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Other than X with compression, the only other remote access option i can think of is nomachine's nx. - There is an official server at [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) but most people use freenx -with the more recent versions of freenx on debian, [you will need to compile it yourself](http://wiki.debian.org/freenx), but ubuntu has a [PPA that should work](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX), and then you can use it with [qtnx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX#Installing_QTNX_.28Opensource_client.29) or the [offical nx clien](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php)t.